# MYSQL/PHP Highest values of two fields: Two queries needed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get two pieces of information from a table: the largest value from one field and the most recent entry. I don't really care about all the other items.  The two fields in question are score and whenadded.  Is there a way to avoid doing two separate queries?

```
"SELECT score FROM scores ORDER BY score DESC limit 1" gives highest score. 
"SELECT whenadded FROM scores ORDER BY whenadded DESC limit 1" gives most recent.
```

However, is there a way to do one query and grab these two pieces of info?  Two queries seems excessive for such a small thing.  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(score), MAX(whenadded) FROM scores
```

This should work.

Comment: Though, there might be an advantage to doing the queries separately if the indexes are separate. This solution would be good with a multi-column index on both score and whenadded.

Comment: How would I grab these values afterwards?  I just quickly tried using while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) using $row['score'] and $row['whenadded'] and it did not seem to get the values.

Comment: @user1260310, Perhaps an improved answer would use column aliases, but as this solution is, you need to use `$row['MAX(score)']` and `$row['MAX(whenadded)']`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the maximum for score and maximum for whenadded

```
SELECT Max(score), Max(whenadded) FROM scores
```